# Why does the method return NaN even though the calculation is correct?

Tags: java, return, nan

I am trying to make a GUI with 2 different JTextField which input is needed for calculating an eGFR value. When printing eGFR in the method `calcAndSetTotal()`, I get the correct calculation (value of eGFR), but when I return eGFR and then call the method `calcAndSetTotal()` in main and try to print it, I get the value "eGFR=NaN" even if I have passed all the input values into doubles.

```java
package NyreFunktion;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class calculation {
    public JFrame frame;
    public JTextField textField;
    public JTextField textField_1;
    
    public double højde;
    public double kreatinin;
    double eGFR=0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    calculation window = new calculation();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                    double value=window.eGFR;
                    System.out.println(value);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        calculation cl= new calculation();
        cl.initialize();
        cl.calcAndSetTotal();
        System.out.println("test=" +cl.calcAndSetTotal());
    }

    public calculation() {
        initialize();
    }

    public void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 450);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(121, 114, 130, 26);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textField);
        textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                 højde =Double.parseDouble(textField.getText());
               System.out.println("Højde: " + højde);
                  calcAndSetTotal();
            }
        });
        
        textField_1 = new JTextField();
        textField_1.setBounds(121, 188, 130, 26);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textField_1);
        textField_1.setColumns(10);
        textField_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent eventt) {
             kreatinin =Double.parseDouble(textField_1.getText());
              System.out.println("kreatinin: " + kreatinin);
              calcAndSetTotal();
            }
        }); 
    }
    
    double calcAndSetTotal() {
           eGFR = højde/kreatinin;
           System.out.println("GFR" + " " + "=" + " " + eGFR);
            
           return eGFR;
    }
}
```

Comment: The code provided is not legal `java` code, it will not compile.

Comment: Please produce a minimal example which illustrates the problem.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65452535/java-why-does-my-method-return-nan-even-though-the-calculation-is-correct

Comment: @Turing85, It compiles but i get the value NaN

Comment: @SarahHayat [No, it does not](https://ideone.com/94V65r)

Comment: @Turing85 we forgot to paste `public class calculation`. It should work now

Answer (score 1):

(I'm assuming that in your real code there is a `public class calculation {` line after the `import` statements.)

---

The real problem is that your code is using two instances of the `calculation` class.

The first `calculation` instance you create in the `run()` method and set it visible.

The second `calculation` instance you create in the `main` method itself and DO NOT set it visible.

The first instance is the one that is being updated when you enter text into the GUI, etc.

The second instance is the one you are using to get the value of `eGFR` that you are printing.  But since this instance was never made visible:

- the action listeners for its text boxes CANNOT have been called, and therefore
- its `højde` and `kreatinin` fields CANNOT have been changed from their default values; i.e. `0.0` and `0.0`, and therefore
- you compute `0.0 / 0.0` which gives the `NaN` that you write to standard output in `main`.

Comment: How do I set the second calculation instance visible?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few thing wrong with your code.

1. First of all I think you made a mistake in calculation and forgot to incapsulate `public calculation()` with a class definition

   ```
   public class calculation {
       public JFrame frame;
       public JTextField textField;
       public JTextField textField_1;

       public double højde = 1;
       public double kreatinin = 1;
       double eGFR = 0;

       public calculation() {
           initialize();
       }

       public void initialize() {...}

       double calcAndSetTotal() {...}
   }
   ```
2. You don't need to call

   ```
   calculation cl= new calculation();
   cl.initialize();
   cl.calcAndSetTotal();
   System.out.println("test=" +cl.calcAndSetTotal());
   ```

You now have two instances running of the same class without it being   visible. That's also what is causing the `NaN` since you divide by zero. A tip I can give you is to check the user input on a division by zero.

Hope this helps

### Edit

After a better understanding of the issue this is more like the behaviour

```
public class calculation {

    public JFrame frame;
    public JTextField textField;
    public JTextField textField_1;

    /*
        when calling calcAndSetTotal() without changing this 
        values first you will get a Nan since højde, kreatinin 
        are both initialised with zero
    */
    public double højde;
    public double kreatinin;
    double eGFR=0;

    static calculation window;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {


        ((Runnable) () -> {
            try {
                window = new calculation();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }).run();
       /*
           Will output NaN since højde, kreatinin are still zero
       */
       System.out.println(window.calcAndSetTotal());

    }

    public calculation() {...}


    public void initialize() {...}

    double calcAndSetTotal() {...}
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226472/discussion-on-answer-by-thevortr3x-java-why-does-the-method-return-nan-even-th).